# Dealing with multiple combinations in C# and xml

Tags: c#, xml, ssis

I have a challenge with complex data validation. During the SSIS load I have to check combination of different elements. I cannot hard code them into C# because they will change a lot. So I came up with idea that I will store them in xml file and script component will pick those rules at run time.

I have a real nightmare to set up xml and c#.

Incoming data is grouped by time and each element belongs to a certain Region. Each Region (there are 8 regions in total) have a list of different combinations of underlying elements.

There will be a list of elements coming from source data:

- BlueA
- RedG
- PinkA
- BlackV
- BlackF

I need to check this against the master list:

1. Combination 1

   If there is single item representing Region it must be one of the first list:

   - Region 1 = BlueA
   - Region 2 = BlackV
   - Region 3 = PinkA
2. Combination 2.

   - Region 1

     a) BlueA, BlueO

     b) BlueA,BlueR

     c) PurpleV,BlueA,BlueR
   - Region 2

     a) BlackV,BlackF

     b) BlackR,BlackL,BlackW

There will be multiple combinations per each Region and there can only one a) or b) or c) can be true. 
For example Region 1- if there is a single element in source it must be BlueA or if there will be multiple elements representing Region 1 it may be one combination from a) or b) or c).

Problem 1
How to design a xml file that could hold these combinations ?

Problem 2
Which elements in c# should I use to hold them. Dictionaries, Lists, ect ?

Could you be so king and advise how to approach this ?

Comment: I doubt if this is on-topic here.

Comment: You can implement this as classes and use XmlSerializer to serialize/deserialize.

Comment: I think your question would be greatly improved by solid examples of input and output. Do not focus on the storage technology (XML) or data structures. Explain what you are trying to solve. Help us understand what a Combination is and why we care. It looks like a Blue* maps to anything in Region 1. What if I have BlueO and BlueR, is that a valid combo for Region 1 or does this violate some rule.

Comment: You can use XML schema (XSD) to validate incoming XML-documents. If you show me some document samples I may try to create example schema for you (and c# code, that will validate documents by this schema).

Comment: The data will be coming to a sql database table, for each group (time Period). I will have different number of rows in element column with different values. First I have to check if a particular element is single per region and I have to check if it exist in the single elements group. then I might have two elements that belong to Region1, in which case I have to check if these two elements are matching combination that has two element.